# Removing numbers and spaces in multiple file names with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to rename multiple mp3 files I have in a folder. They start with something like "1 Hotel California - The Eagles" and so on. I would like it to be just "Hotel California - The Eagles".
Also, there could be a "05 Hotel California - The Eagles" as well, which means removing the number from a different files would create duplicates, which is the problem I am facing. I want it to replace existing files/overwrite/delete one of them or whatever a solution might be.
P.S, Adding "3" to the "1234567890 " would remove the "3" from the .mp3 extension

I am new to python, but here is the code I am using to implement this

```
    import os


    def renamefiles():

        list = os.listdir(r"E:\NEW")
        print(list)
        path = os.getcwd()
        print(path)
        os.chdir(r"E:\NEW")
        for name in list:
            os.rename(name, name.translate(None, "124567890 "))
        os.chdir(path)

    renamefiles()
```

And here is the error I get
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Any help on how I could rename the files correctly would be highly appreciated!

Comment: what should happen if you do end up with files that have the same name after removing the digit/s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch an `OSError` and also use `glob` to find the .mp3 files:

```
import os
from glob import iglob

def renamefiles(pth):
    os.chdir(pth)
    for name in iglob("*.mp3"):
        try:
            os.rename(name, name.translate(None, "124567890").lstrip())
        except OSError:
            print("Caught error for {}".format(name))
            # os.remove(name) ?
```

What you do when you catch the error is up to you, you could keep some record of names found and increment a count for each or leave as is.

If the numbers are always at the start you can also just lstrip then away so you can then use 3 safely:

```
 os.rename(name, name.lstrip("0123456789 "))
```

using one of your example strings:

```
In [2]: "05 Hotel California - The Eagles.mp3".lstrip("01234567890 ")
Out[2]: 'Hotel California - The Eagles.mp3'
```

Using your original approach could never work as desired as you would remove all spaces:

```
In [3]: "05 Hotel California - The Eagles.mp3".translate(None,"0124567890 ")
Out[3]: 'HotelCalifornia-TheEagles.mp3'
```

If you don't care what file gets overwritten you can use `shutil.move`:

```
import os
from glob import iglob
from shutil import move

def renamefiles(pth):
    os.chdir(pth)
    for name in iglob("*.mp3"):
        move(name, name.translate(None, "124567890").lstrip())
```

On another note, don't use `list` as  a variable name.

Comment: using the code you wrote, i am unaware of where to put the path to the mp3 files? i tried changing "pth" to r"E:\NEW" but it gave me an error, sorry im quite new to programming. Also, yes the numbers are always at the start but sometimes theres a dash after the number and before the name of the song. (1 XX-XX.mp3, 06 - XX-XX.mp3)

Comment: Just call the function with the path as argument

Comment: it gave me a WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied. Can replace existing file with same name/delete file completely if it is already found be a solution?

Comment: That is a permissions error so you would need to run the script as the administrator. Do you want to overwrite the files with the same names regardless?

Comment: i have IDLE running as administrator. and yes sure, anything to fix this issue, they are the same file anyways just with different names

Comment: save this code in a file as `script.py` http://pastebin.com/nU8XAaKZ, then start a cmd prompt as admin and run `python script.py E:\NEW`, not sure on windows if you need to wrap paths in quotes or not as I don't ever use windows

Comment: okay, so i opened cmd as admin, typed python and got the >>>, but when i type script.py it says name 'script' not defined,  how do i give it the location of the script? i tried typging E:\NEW after script.py with and without quotations and it gave me invalid syntax

Comment: you don't start python, you run the the script i.e  `python script.py E:\NEW`, save the code in the link in a file called `script.py`, cd to the directory you saved it in and run  `python script.py E:\NEW`

Comment: okay, it gave me IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'JamesBay-HoldBackTheRiver.mp3" even thought i have cmd as admin!

Comment: does it fail straight away on the very first file?

Comment: Also you right clicked the cmd shortcut and selected run as administrator?

Comment: yes, but the folder already has like 20 edited file names from previous attempts, and it includes "JamesBay-HoldBackTheRiver.mp3". So the problem is renaming when the file already exists. And no, i searched for cmd and pressed cntrl+shift+enter, it says "Administrator: Command Prompt" at the top of the cmd window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90271/discussion-between-omar-younis-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: okay got it to work! i right clicked the folder and changed its properties, it was on "read only" which is weird since some of the files did get edited. anyways thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to verify that the names being changed actually changed. If the name doesn't have digits or spaces in it, the `translate` will return the same string, and you'll try to rename `name` to `name`, which Windows rejects. Try:

```
for name in list:
    newname = name.translate(None, "124567890 ")
    if name != newname:
        os.rename(name, newname)
```

Note, this will still fail if the file target exists, which you'd probably want if you were accidentally collapsing two names into one. But if you want silent replace behavior, if you're on Python 3.3 or higher, you can change `os.rename` to `os.replace` to silently overwrite; on earlier Python, you can explicitly `os.remove` before calling `os.rename`.

Comment: You don't (`str.maketrans` will do this for you), I just completely reversed the two prototypes of the `str.translate` method in my head.

Comment: Yes, but it's a lot more complicated than just using `ord` in that case. You may as well use `str.maketrans` in that case anyway (though it's best to do it outside the loop).

Comment: Eh; I'm usually in favor of letting the language APIs do the work rather than reinventing the wheel (so if `str.maketrans` has additional optimizations, you're not handicapping yourself). `tbl = str.maketrans('', '', '124567890 ')` is rather more self-documenting to me, but to each their own.

Comment: Per `translate` you mean? Because table generation is actually faster with `str.maketrans` in general. And the per `translate` cost is implementation specific (replacing with the empty string is coincidentally faster because of test ordering in CPython) and differs minimally, so I'm not inclined to care much about jitter like that. `str.translate` in Py3 is incredibly slow (though a bug I filed reduced that cost for ASCII translation), and most fixes for it would involve making `str.maketrans` return a special purpose `dict` that can be used more efficiently than raw `dict`s.

Comment: if name != newname:, os.remove(path),  os.replace(name, newname) you mean like this? it gave me "WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied:"

Comment: @OmarYounis: You did `os.remove(path)`; presumably you want `os.remove(newname)`.

Comment: changed, still gave me WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied , even though i have IDLE running as administrator

Comment: Can you figure out which file is broken? At a guess, you've probably got directories in the listing, though that's just the most likely source of failure.

Answer (score 2):

instead of using name.translate, import the re lib (regular expressions) and use something like

```
"(?:\d*)?\s*(.+?).mp3"
```

as your pattern. You can then use

```
Match.group(1)
```

as your rename.

For dealing with multiple files, add an if statement that checks if the file already exists in the library like this:

```
os.path.exists(dirpath)
```

where dirpath is the directory that you want to check in

Comment: @RNar: You can run Javascript/HTML/CSS code in the browser. When posting an answer, you have to select the paper with angle brackets (<>) on it, instead of the regular {}, which just indents four spaces. Your answer had "Run code snippet" buttons, so I thought it finally works for Python. Unfortunately, it seems that it does not.

Comment: @JeanNassar yeah sorry, I accidentally pressed the wrong button, that was my bad

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to easily get any of the answers to work with Python 3.5, so here's one that works under that condition:

```
import os
import re


def rename_files():
    path = os.getcwd()
    file_names = os.listdir(path)
    for name in file_names:
        os.rename(name, re.sub("[0-9](?!\d*$)", "", name))

rename_files()
```

This should work for a list of files like "1 Hotel California - The Eagles.mp3", renaming them to "Hotel California - The Eagles.mp3" (so the extension is untouched).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what you want is:

- create a new filename removing *leading* numbers
- if that new filename exists, remove it
- rename the file to that new filename

The following code should work (not tested).

```
import os
import string

class FileExists(Exception):
    pass

def rename_files(path, ext, remove_existing=True):
    for fname in os.listdir(path):
        # test if the file name ends with the expected 
        # extension else skip it
        if not fname.endswith(ext):
            continue

        # chdir is not a good idea, better to work
        # with absolute path whenever possible
        oldpath = os.path.join(path, fname)
        # remove _leading_ digits then remove all whitespaces
        newname = fname.lstrip(string.digits).strip()
        newpath = os.path.join(path, newname)
        # check if the file already exists
        if os.path.exists(newpath):
            if remove_existing:
                # it exists and we were told to
                # remove existing file:
                os.remove(newpath)
            else:
                # it exists and we were told to
                # NOT remove existing file:
                raise FileExists(newpath)
        # ok now we should be safe
        os.rename(oldpath, newpath)

# only execute the function if we are called directly
# we dont want to do anything if we are just imported
# from the Python shell or another script or module
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # exercice left to the reader:
    # add command line options / arguments handling
    # to specify the path to browse, the target 
    # extension and whether to remove existing files
    # or not
    rename_files(r"E:\NEW", ".mp3", True)
```

Comment: it gave me this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: Sorry it should have been `os.remove` not `os.path.remove`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change directory to where *.mp3 files are located and execute 2 lines of below with python:

```
import os,re
for filename in os.listdir():
    os.rename(filename, filname.strip(re.search("[0-9]{2}", filename).group(0)))
```